Framer Motion's Reorder component to stop propagation when certain element is dragged
Is there a way to stop the <Reorder.Item> to be draggable horizontally if a <Slider /> child element from shadcn is dragged? I want the widget component to be draggable anywhere except when the slider is dragged.
Unfortunately, I cannot provide a codepen playground or anything so I will just drop the simplified code I have below.
I have this wrapper component which uses the Reorder.Group and Reorder.Item from framer motion:
export const WidgetWrapper = () => {
return (
  <div className="flex gap-4 overflow-x-auto scrollbar pb-4 mb-4 transition-opacity opacity-100 scale-100 origin-center">
    <div className="flex gap-4 pr-2"> 
       <Reorder.Group
          values={widgets}
          onReorder={setWidgets}
          className="flex gap-4 pr-2"
          axis="x"
        >
          {widgets.map((widget) => (
              <Reorder.Item 
                key={`${widget.id}`}
                value={widget}
              >
                <MyWidget />
              </Reorder.Item>
          ))}
     </div>
   </div>
)
}

And this is code for the Widget component:
export const MyWidget = () => {
   return (
     <div>
        <Slider
          step={1}
          value={[0, 100]}
          max={200}
        />
     </div>
   )
}

This is a simplified component but you get the gist. I tried adding the e.stopPropagation() when the slider is dragged but to no avail, or maybe I was using it wrong. I cannot seem to find anything useful in the docs. Any help is really appreciated.
